# Can I use R language to connect a remote server and do some operations?

Tags: r, rcurl, shiny

I'm running a system on AWS EC2 server. The system is built by R language, and produces rds files(the results of some models) every day.

Now, I want to create a shiny app on shinyapps.io, which can send the input data to the AWS server, use the model files to calculate a result, and get the result to show on my shiny app.

Is there a easy method in R language to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [ramazon](https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/ramazon)?  It is the only package I know of for combining shiny and aws.  But I believe that puts shiny directly on AWS.  Not sure if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. But actually, my problem is that our client doesn't know how to connect to a server. So I want to make it possible to connect to Shiny with a url. It seems like the scp function of Rcurl works fine on it. I will have a try. Thanks!